# Why there is giving, name 'pd ' is not defined error?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, nameerror

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

dataset = pd.read_csv('homeprice.csv')
print(dataset)
```

**Output**

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv('homeprice.csv')
>         2 print(dataset)
>
> NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: And I am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: If this is two cells, the top cell with imports may not have been run first? The code looks fine.

Comment: Run the cell that contains the `import pandas as pd` will solve your problem.

Comment: Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI sir I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using a Jupiter notebook so you may have two code cells:

First is with the imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
```

And the second is with the functionality:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('homeprice.csv')
print(dataset)
```

In Jupiter notebooks you may run each cell separately. If this is what you do, you should remember the run the first cell before you execute the second one for the first time. This would make sure the right stuff is imported in the current context for you second cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0.0rc2
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Or

Just go with the latest TensorFlow version in the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)